# python - how to compare a key of the dictionary with a string character

Tags: python, dictionary

I am new to python and I need to compare a character in string with a key in a dictionary. But I am not able to figure out a way to compare that character with a key. I am only able to compare it with the value at dict[key]

I am trying to implement something like this:

```
score = {"a": 1, "c": 3, "b": 3, "e": 1, "d": 2, "g": 2, 
     "f": 4, "i": 1, "h": 4, "k": 5, "j": 8, "m": 3, 
     "l": 1, "o": 1, "n": 1, "q": 10, "p": 3, "s": 1, 
     "r": 1, "u": 1, "t": 1, "w": 4, "v": 4, "y": 4, 
     "x": 8, "z": 10}

def compare(word):
   res = 0
   for letter in word:
       if score[**What should i put in here**] == letter:
          res += score[letter]
   return res
```

where score[key] represents the value at that particular key as a whole. Is there a way to compare a key to the letter, instead of the value?

My aim is to compare the "letter" in "word" with the keys in dictionary and add the values against the characters and return the result.

Comment: `for letter in word: res += score.get(letter, 0)`

Comment: Are you trying to check if the letter belongs to the dictionary as a key?

Comment: Is `dict` supposed to be `score`...?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Looks like you're thinking about this strangely. All you need to do is check if the letter is in your `score` dict, and if it is, to add that number to your total.

```
def compare(word):
    res = 0
    for letter in word:
        if letter in score:
            res += score[letter]
    return res
```

However there's an easier way to do this. Since you're just using `res` as an accumulator, you can add `score[letter]` if it exists or `0` if it doesn't. This is easy using the `dict.get` method.

```
def compare(word):
    res = 0
    for letter in word:
        res += score.get(letter, 0)
        # dict.get(key, defaultvalue)
    return res
```

In fact you can even make it into an ugly `lambda`.

```
compare = lambda word: sum([scores.get(letter,0) for letter in word])
```

Answer (score 1):

```
score = {"a": 1, ...}

def compare(word):
   res = 0
   for letter in word:
       if letter in score:
           res += score[letter]
   return res
```

That's probably what you want. You can even omit `if letter in score` if you're sure all your letters will exist in `score`. You don't really need to *compare* anything.

Answer (score 1):

```
score = {"a": 1, "c": 3, "b": 3, "e": 1, "d": 2, "g": 2, 
 "f": 4, "i": 1, "h": 4, "k": 5, "j": 8, "m": 3, 
 "l": 1, "o": 1, "n": 1, "q": 10, "p": 3, "s": 1, 
 "r": 1, "u": 1, "t": 1, "w": 4, "v": 4, "y": 4, 
 "x": 8, "z": 10}

def compare(word):
    res = 0
    for letter in word:
       if letter in score:
          res += score[letter]
    return res
```

Answer (score 0):

As the other answer by Adam has pointed out you are thinking about this in a strange way. There is NO way to get the key of the dictionary score using something like `score['*get_me_the_key*']`.

If you really want the keys. `score.keys()` will give you a list of keys in the dictionary. Something like this:

```
keys = score.keys()
print keys
['a', 'c', 'b', 'e', 'd', 'g', 'f', 'i', 'h', 'k', 'j', 'm', 'l', 'o', 'n', 'q', 'p', 's', 'r', 'u', 't', 'w', 'v', 'y', 'x', 'z']
```

Answer (score 0):

```
dict = {"a": 1, "c": 3, "b": 3, "e": 1, "d": 2, "g": 2, 
 "f": 4, "i": 1, "h": 4, "k": 5, "j": 8, "m": 3, 
 "l": 1, "o": 1, "n": 1, "q": 10, "p": 3, "s": 1, 
 "r": 1, "u": 1, "t": 1, "w": 4, "v": 4, "y": 4, 
 "x": 8, "z": 10}

def compare(word):

res = 0

for letter in word:

   if letter in dict:

      res += dict['letter']

return res
```

example:

```
dict['c']
```

get corresponding value 3

Answer (score 0):

I recognize this problem in the Codecademy: Python course. In the problem you are doing, you must add `word = word.lower()` at the start of the function. Otherwise, if you check for words containing capital letters, the program will get errors. In other words, "D" is not in the dictionary, but "d" is. Hope this helps.